# Count DIFFERENT results in a rails find call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, count

Let's suppose I have a model with only two fields: **name** and **street name**.

How would I find out the number of *different* *street names* in a controller method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return the total number of *different* street_names

```
Model.group(:street_name).all.count
```

This will return an ordered hash with a count of names on each street

```
Model.group(:street_name).count
```

Answer (score 3):

why don't you do a 'count_by_sql' where you would use the request `select count(*) from (select distinct(street_name) from <table_name>)`

Otherwhise you can do it in ruby: `<ModelName>.all.group_by(&:street_name).size`

Answer (score 3):

Try this !

```
Model.find(:all,:select => 'DISTINCT street_name').size
```